# Puppeteer: select script tag containing certain text

Tags: xpath, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm trying to crawl a facebook photo page which contains several script tags. I want to select a specific one which contains "nextMedia". I did this:

```
code1 = await page.$x('//script[contains(., "nextMedia")]')
console.log(code1);
```

I get an ElementHandle object as a result. How do I extract the whole `<script> ... </script>` HTML code from this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const code1 = await page.$x('//script[contains(., "nextMedia")]')

const content = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, code1[0]);
console.log(content);
```